# Is it possible to control how a command is recorded as a keyboard macro?

Tags: keyboard-macros

Some actions don't work well when repeated in a keyboard macro.

For example, `dabbrev-expand` may give a different expansion based on the surrounding context.

I would like to repeat the action as if I had typed in the text that was expanded, or at least make it expand to the same text when re-run as a keyboard macro.

Is there a way to control how a keyboard macro is stored?